# plsql query to fetch mismatch records

Tags: plsql

I have two tables where one table data is as below

[image]

how to fetch the row from table2 which are not ranged to abc (example :- 13 should be ranged to abc and 21 should be ranged def in plsql

Comment: "13 should be ranged to abc" - why? What's the *connection* between those two tables which tells that 13 is result you want?

Comment: If we consider c2 is parent and c1 is child of tale 1 and table2 should contain both parent and child and ranged

Comment: I'm sorry, I just don't understand what you are saying.